# Transaction error 251 with spring data mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

We have a spring boot application. We use mongo Atlas. Spring data mongo is used to interact with the db. Once in a while we see a problem with transactional methods. The problem happens when service is not called for a few hours. The next call to a transactional method after that idle time results in this exception.

```
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 251 and error message 'Given transaction number 1 does not match any in-progress transactions. The active transaction number is -1' on server azure-..........mongodb.net:27017
at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:660)
at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:650)
at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:582)
at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:650)
at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:78)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:178)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:135)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2789)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2549)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.doFind(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:220)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.oneValue(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:132)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.lambda$getExecution$4(AbstractMongoQuery.java:159)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.doExecute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:132)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:107)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.findBySomething
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor119.invoke
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.findBySomething
at com.app.MyService(MyServiceImpl.java:25)
```

Following calls work as expected. The problem is not reproducible with local mongo.

To fix this I am trying to add a MethodInterceptor (this interceptor is added with a MongoRepositoryFactoryBean) with RetryTemplate. This is the only solution I've managed to find on the internet.

```
import org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate;

@CustomLog
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RetryRepositoryMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

private final RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

@Override
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    return retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {
        if (retryContext.getRetryCount() > 0) {
            log.error("Retrying mongo call because MongoTransactionException happened");
        }
        return invocation.proceed();
    });
}

}
```

Now the first exception triggers the retry, and on the second call I see a new exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No fragment found for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.app.repository.MyRepository.findBySomething(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:280)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at com.app.config.jpa.RetryRepositoryMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(RetryRepositoryMethodInterceptor.java:26)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:209)
at com.app.config.jpa.RetryRepositoryMethodInterceptor.invoke(RetryRepositoryMethodInterceptor.java:21)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.findBySomething
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor132.invoke
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.findBySomething
at com.app.MyService.findBySomething(MyServiceImpl.java:25)
```

This exception doesn't tell me anything. At this point I don't have any idea how to fix the problem. I hope you'll kindly give me a hand.